# Slow performance reading parquet

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyarrow

I have a 4.4GB parquet file that has ~100MM rows. I have done the following to load the file to memory:

```
sudo mkdir /ram/
sudo mount ramfs -t ramfs /ram
```

This way IO is not a problem. Then I use the following code to load the file:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pyarrow.parquet as pq


def get_df():
    return pq.read_table(
        source='/ram/001.parquet',
        memory_map=True,
    ).to_pandas(
        split_blocks=True,
        strings_to_categorical=True,
    )


print(f'{datetime.now()} -> Loading to DF...')

df = get_df()

print(f'{datetime.now()} -> DF loaded!')

print(df.head())

print(f'{datetime.now()} -> DF has a size of {df.memory_usage(deep=False).sum() * 1.0 / 1073741824} GB')
```

This is completed in ~3 minutes. If I re-write the file to have snappy compression, the file goes down to 2.8GB, however the performance doesn't go up by much.

Is there something that can be done to increase performance here?

Comment: Since there is no I/O I would expect compression to only make things worse (it adds CPU work).  Have you tried uncompressed?  That being said, 3 minutes seems rather excessive for 4GB, regardless of compression.  How many columns do you have?  How was this parquet file created?  How many row groups do you have?  What sorts of data types do you have?

Comment: I'd suggest measuring the runtime of `pq.read_table` and `to_pandas` separately.

Comment: @Pace The file was created with a Redshift unload command, it has about 30 columns, 100MM rows, has no row groups and most of the data types are strings and timestamps. the performance between compressed and uncompressed is almost the same, varies for just a few seconds.

Comment: Every parquet file has at least one row group.  Can you share the output of `pq.ParquetFile('/ram/001.parquet').metadata`?  Also, 100 million rows x 30 columns, assuming they are all 8 byte timestamps, would be ~24GB of data.  Potentially even larger given that you have strings.

Comment: And to repeat @0x26res' comment: be sure to time the conversion to pandas separately. Especially if you have a lot of strings, this conversion is quite expensive and is typically the bottleneck (the Arrow strings (contiguous in memory) need to be converted to Python string objects)